# Can't run simple code in console via node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote simple code in JS

```
const a = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];

console.log(a.flat());
```

And I have error like this

```
console.log(a.flat());
          ^

TypeError: a.flat is not a function
```

I'm running code via node

```
node test.js
```

Do I need install some packages? I'm working on macOS.

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Try `node -version`.

Comment: `.flat` is relatively new to JS - what's your Node version? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) says you need Node 11 or above.

Comment: Should upgrade your node js version to the last one or the LTS at least

Comment: My bad - I have version 10.15 right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `Array.flat` is not available in nodejs (v10).

Ah yes v11+ only - see compatability table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: Thanks. Next time I will check compatability with node on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an outdated version of Node.JS - as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility), you need Node.JS 11 or newer.

Download the latest version of Node.JS from [the website](https://nodejs.org).

If you can't use/get the latest version, you could use the [MDN polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Alternative) which works for multiple levels of nesting:

```
function flattenDeep(arr1) {
   return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
}
```